# Using a dictionary in a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a SortedDictionary (of string, string) containing Names and IDs. The Values in the dictionary are the names and the keys are the IDs. These could be reversed if it makes life easier.

What I'm hoping to do is display the names in the drop list of a combo box and, when the user selects a name, the code will be filled in in the second column of the DataGridView.

So far, I've got this:

```
    bindSrcPDF = New BindingSource(dicSorted, Nothing)
    col = grdAuthors.Columns(0)
    col.DisplayMember = "Value"
    col.DataSource = bindSrcPDF

    col = grdAuthors.Columns(1)
    col.DisplayMember = "Key"
    col.DataSource = bindSrcPDF
```

Which shows the names in the droplist of the combo boxes in each row, but I can't figure out how to get the textbox in the second column to display the code that corresponds to the name selected.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must load value into Combobox first.

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Name"
```

Then chose On Click Event. In this event you write your code to clear old data and load new source to DataGridView

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
dataGridView1.Refresh()
dataGridView1.DataSource = your_data_source
```

For Handle datagridcomboboxColumn you can view link below
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/453d7584-d4d3-495b-b3ed-5998758d9614/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-selection-changed?forum=winformsdatacontrols

or

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/338689-datagridview-combobox-selected-value-changed/

Comment: Thanks, Minh, but I'm still not clear about this - and I suspect I didn't explain the original problem clearly enough. The code snippet above already populates the droplists of the combo boxes. I haven't managed to connect the combobox and the textbox to the dictionary the way I wanted though - what I'd like to happen is that the DataGridView "looks up" the corresponding code when the user selects a name in the combobox field.
There doesn't seem to be an OnClickEvent for a combo box which is in a DataGridView - just the general one for the grid itself. I'll see if I can persuade it to work.

Comment: For Handle datagridcomboboxColumn you can view link above